# How to setup Visual Studio Professional 2022 to create and compile projects in FORTRAN with MinGW

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, gfortran

So, for background, my most recent programming experience has consisted of Python (anaconda) and matlab, for like the last 7 years or so. I've done C/C++, Obj-C, C#, and a few other languages in the distant past, but I'm super rusty on makefiles and all that.

For work, we have some ancient code written in FORTRAN77 that I need to be able to run. I've got MinGW and gfortran installed (via MSYS), and have gotten sample programs to compile just fine, but for this project I'm going off of images of code, and do not have the original code available in its original digital form. As such, I'm having to do a lot of corrections (I ran it through OCR), and will have to correct some peculiarities specific to whatever unknown mainframe it was originally written for. So I would REALLY like to be able to use VS pro to edit, run and debug the document (about 1k lines of code, very messy).

I'm brand new to VS, and as I said, it's been ages since I did anything but python or matlab, let alone messed with makefiles and toolpaths and such, so I'll be very grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction. Oh, and one important last note: one of the commercial fortran extensions is not a viable option, due to this being a small project, the fact that we probably won't have to mess with fortran often in the future, and our onerous capex request process, hence my desire to use gfortran. Thanks!

Comment: The Intel oneapi compiler integrates with VS2022 and is free.

Comment: windows or mac? On windows Intel Fortran an option by downloading the free oneAPI took kit (Base + HPC). But there is a bug currently with VS integration and a workaround (see https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Do-not-upgrade-VS-2022-to-version-v17-2-It-breaks-all/td-p/1382358)

Comment: Can't use the intel version because it has commercial licensing restrictions, I think. Unless I'm wrong? On Windows 10.

Comment: You will need to check your requirements against the [end user license](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/news/free-intel-software-developer-tools.html), but I suspect you are wrong.

Comment: @IanH I'll dig into it. Thank you for the advice. :)